# Quicklook unable to display document without file extension

Tags: ios, swift, quicklook

I am using `QuickLook` framework of iOS to display document which works fine with the files which have an extension. But if I try to view a file which don't have any file extension but are of the valid file type then preview is not displaying.

Suppose if I try to view pdf file with name 12456.pdf then it shows the preview but same file without extension 123456 will not work.

Is there any way to preview documents even if there is no file extension.

Following is preview of file without extension.
[image: preview]

Also is there any method to know if the document can be view properly or not.
I have found following method on [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller/1617016-canpreview) but dont know how to use it.

```
canPreview(_:)

Indicates whether or not the Quick Look preview controller can display an item.
```

Comment: It is quite unlikely, cuz i had the same problem before. So what you have to do is that, when you download the file, make sure to add a valid extension. It can be PNG or PDF ect

Comment: @progammingBeignner so you are suggesting that i should add file extension manually, but i have different types of file so how would i know what extension need to be added.

Comment: that is not what i meant... You need to know the source of your file.. You download it somewhere right? You should get the extension from the source... You should never add extension manually.

Comment: well file url will be like this `http://firebasesorage/abcd`  where `abcd` is filename. so you can see there is no extension. so now i will download this file in to my local storage and try to open it. suppose it is in document folder like this `Document/abcd` now I will try to open this file which can be either pdf or word or any other.

Comment: That is, then, the servers side problem. When you are uploading the file, you need to fix it in the way that the file stored will have an extension

Comment: so final conclusion is that extension is mandatory. without extension a file can not be preview in `Quick Look`